# Is there any query/procedure in MS Access to find whether all the queries in MS Access uses a particular column of a table?

Tags: ms-access-2007

I want to find the names of queries in MS Access which are using a column of a particular table. Is there any predefined functionality in MS Access ?

Answer (score 0):

The [FMS Total Access Analyzer](http://fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/documentation/index.html) can reveal this.

Or you could write a loop that parses the *SQL* property of your queries:

```
Public Sub ListSql()

    Dim qd  As DAO.QueryDef

    For Each qd In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
        Debug.Print qd.Name & ":"
        Debug.Print qd.Sql
    Next

    Set qd = Nothing

End Sub
```